# Android AVD- modifying API level, changing the APP view

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi I was using Google API level 7 for my App.
I coded all layouts in dip unit. Now I installed Google API 8, changed my project to use level 8.
But, after launching the App, getting modified view. For e.g- the length increased for a list-view. Also, service call is not working. Restarting eclipse didn't solve the issue.

Then again switched back to Google API 7, now the service calls working fine. But, having layout issues like- font-size got bigger and list-view having increased height.

- so, is there anything am missing? or why the layout is changing in different API Level! I don't have a device; will all the element measurements change in device?

Comment: which layout are you use? if linear layout then no problem because when you check it on device it will get in proper manner.now you got problem of size of emulator so click on avd > click on avd item(Google api 8) > click edit button >  set built in : HVGA >edit AVD > then run

Comment: Thanx scorpio
am using Linear Layout to hold the listview.
Previously, i had done the same & also selected the HVGA, but, got a bit small window. Now, again following ur instructions, got  bigger window.
 But, still fonts are big and listview is overflowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which layout are you use? if linear layout then no problem because when you check it on device it will get in proper manner.now you got problem of size of emulator so click on avd > click on avd item(Google api 8) > click edit button > set built in : HVGA >edit AVD > then run
>
> dont worry check it in device it will get properly.

Comment: so, now if fix the font and elemnt heights in Level 8 and switch back to API level 7, will there be font and height issue again??